# PSE10 Insert Invisible Watermark

Tags: copyright, photoshop-elements, watermark, png

I need to put an invisible watermark in some of my PSE10 edited PNG files, but since I am an amateur, I probably don't need an online subscription right now.  How do I easily put an invisible watermark in my PNG files using PSE10 without subscribing to an imaging service.

When I go to Filter->Digimarc all I see is the option "Read Watermark".  When I search through the PSE10 help, all I see are instructions on how to read such an invisible watermark.

Thanks,

Shawn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off I am not sure if there is an easy way to create an invisible watermark in PSE without buying a Digimarc subscription. With that said there is a way to create an (almost) invisible watermark using the blue channel and layer styles but this is not possible in PSE. [Here is a tutorial](http://www.psdbox.com/tutorials/create-an-invisible-watermark-in-photoshop/) on how this is done in PS. (Maybe download the [trial version of Photoshop](http://downloadcs6.com) to insert the watermark?)

With all of that said if you are going to release the PNG file into the public via the web license the file using [creative commons](http://creativecommons.org/choose/).

Answer (score -2):

Gimp is a free open source program, it does pretty much everything that PSE does. You can use that to create your watermarks.

Once you have a watermark, and if you want several files watermarked at once, you can use a free watermarking program like [SquiggleMark](http://www.osletek.com/squigglemark/). (Disclaimer: I am the author of SquiggleMark)

Comment: The question was specifically about invisible watermarks. I can't see that your software offers this.

Comment: The program I mentioned does transparent watermarks.

Comment: Invisible is not the same as transparent! An invisible watermark can only be read from the image digitally, and is not visible to someone looking at it.